# Swift: Update UITableView from UIButton inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController called `TableVC` and a custom UITableViewCell called `CustomCell`. Inside the `CustomCell` class, I have a UIButton:

```
@IBAction func reloadTableView(sender: AnyObject) {

    TableVC().tableView.reloadData()

}
```

When the corresponding button is tapped, it does not seem to update/reload my table view. Why not, and what can I do to resolve my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `tableView` of a cell in several ways. The superview of your cell should be of type `UITableView` so in your cell you can `(superview as? UITableView)?.reloadData()`.

However a more stable method is using the hierarchy of responders. I have created a really useful extension that allows you to find the next of responder of a particular type such a `UITableView`.

```
extension UIResponder {

    func nextResponder<T: UIResponder>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T? {

        switch nextResponder() {

        case let responder as T:
            return responder

        case let .Some(responder):
            return responder.nextResponder(ofType: type)

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is a recursive function, so it climbs the responder hierarchy until it successfully casts a responder to the provided type or runs out of responders to try and cast.

```
@IBAction func reloadTableView(sender: AnyObject) {

    nextResponder(ofType: UITableView.self)?.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are clicking a button you are creating a new instance of TableVC and you are reloading the that tableview data. instead of this store a TableVC object somewhere and reload data on that. either create a IBOutlet of TableVC or create a property in a class and assign TableVC ref to that.

Comment: @madrhatter is this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

use only

```
   self.tableView.reloadData()
```